# How to create own push service for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In my iOS app, I need to fetch data from server very frequently to check whether new data is available. I can't use APN because there won't be internet available, our app is an b2b app, we only use a local server to interact with. Is it possible to create a push service in the local server? If so how to I setup a push service in the local server. So that the local server can send push notifications to the app.

Comment: you need to have a connection always open with your local server if you need the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new Background Fetch in iOS 7 to regularly fetch new data.

Apple Doc (Fetching Small Amounts of Content Regularly):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4

Tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch--mobile-20520

Comment: How often background fetch takes place? Will the background fetch called every 5 mins?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to host your own push service (i.e. not using the APNS server), you could implement background fetch (iOS7 ++) and set up local notifications informing the user about new content.

Comment: I tried background fetch. But it is not calling often, iOS only decides when to fetch the data. My app need to fetch data for every 5 or 10 mins.

Comment: As you already said, the system decides on the appropriate time to give background execution time.